# Using unique index to limit amount of rows per column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've got a really large MySQL table that is simply too big to query frequently (500m+ rows). What I've done is cache the results I need in another table called "recent".

In the "recent" table the schema looks like this

USER_ID

PAGE_ID

DISPLAY_ORDER

I've put a unique index on USER_ID and DISPLAY_ORDER as I only want to store up to 64 records per user in this table. As such, DISPLAY_ORDER is simply an int that goes up to 64. The rows are updated using a REPLACE INTO.

Is this a good approach? Or should I periodically just delete data from the table once a user hits over 64 rows. I need to take performance into consideration. The master table that's at 500 million will grow to 1 billion over the next few months, and at 64 rows per user that means the "recent" table will be quite large, too...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could consider [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) your underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would seriously consider moving to a Big Data NoSQL database.  Something like Cassandra or HBase, which both have very good performance with large sets of data.  Let 5-10 clustered nodes do the work for you with a MapReduce rather than one giant monolithic server trying to scan and seek through that many records.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both eggyal and Todd Nakamura.

**eggyal**: partition your data
When dealing with datasets that large you really need to partition the data so you have the chance to run your queries on a subset of the data verses the whole thing.


**Todd Nakamura**: investigate a different database technology.
This problem does seem like a NoSQL data store would be a good solution.  It would allow extremely large datasets, and the ability to use Map/Reduce (Hadoop) to parallalize queries.